# (vuetify in nuxt js) autocomplete isnt update relative to items prop

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Every input in search i update the items prop but the v-autocomplete become empty
although the data in my component changed
i tried to add the no-filter prop it didnt help i guess something with the reactivity destroyed
i allso tried with computed property as an items but still same result

Every input in search i update the items prop but the v-autocomplete become empty
although the data in my component changed
i tried to add the no-filter prop it didnt help i guess something with the reactivity destroyed
i allso tried with computed property as an items but still same result

```js
<script>
import ProductCartCard from "~/components/cart/ProductCartCard";

export default {
  name: "search-app",
  components: {
    ProductCartCard
  },
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      filteredItems: [],
      search: null,
      select: null
    };
  },
  watch: {
    search(val) {
      if (!val || val.length == 0) {
        this.filteredItems.splice(0, this.filteredItems.length);

        return;
      } else {
        val !== this.select && this.querySelections(val);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    querySelections(v) {
      this.loading = true;
      // Simulated ajax query
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.filteredItems.splice(
          0,
          this.filteredItems.length,
          ...this.items.filter(i => {
            return (i.externalName || "").toLowerCase().includes((v || "").toLowerCase());
          })
        );

        this.loading = false;
      }, 500);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="search-app-container">
    <v-autocomplete
      v-model="select"
      :loading="loading"
      :items="filteredItems"
      :search-input.sync="search"
      cache-items
      flat
      hide-no-data
      hide-details
      label="searchProduct"
      prepend-icon="mdi-database-search"
      solo-inverted
    >
      <template v-slot:item="data">
        <ProductCartCard :regularProduct="data" />
      </template>
    </v-autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the caveat of the `v-autocomplete` as described in the documentation:

> When using objects for the items prop, you must associate item-text and item-value with existing properties on your objects. These values are defaulted to text and value and can be changed.

That may fix your issue

Comment: ty you are right  but now when i type data and than delete it is showing all data instead nothing

Comment: it was the cache-items prop now everything fine